# How to test HTML content with React testing library

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-testing-library

Currently I am writing a test to test the content that is inside (HTML content), but it seems I cannot test that properly with React testing library. It can find the id value of that, but how do I get the HTML content inside that element.

```js
import React from 'react';

export const TopBar = () => {
    return (
        <div className="dashboard-title-component">
            <div>
                <div data-testid="title-content">Dashboard Menu</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

import React from "react";
import { render } from "@testing-library/react";
import { TopBar } from "./TopBar";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import { store } from "../../Store";
import { screen } from "@testing-library/dom";
import "@testing-library/jest-dom/extend-expect";

test("It should check if content matches", () => {
    render(
        <Provider store={store}>
            <TopBar/>
        </Provider>
    )
    const checkContent = screen.getAllByTestId("title-content");
    expect(checkContent.text()).toBe("Dashboard Menu");
});
```

[image]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You're using `"@testing-library/jest-dom/extend-expect"` which provides a set of custom jest matchers that you can use, fore example you have [`toHaveTextContent(text: string | RegExp, options?: {normalizeWhitespace: boolean})`](https://github.com/testing-library/jest-dom#tohavetextcontent) that you can use here:

```
const checkContent = screen.getByTestId("title-content");
expect(checkContent).toHaveTextContent("Dashboard Menu");
```

Answer (score 3):

It is possible to also test whole HTML node structure this way:

```
const checkContent = screen.getByTestId("title-content");
expect(checkContent.outerHTML)
    .toEqual("<div data-testid=\"title-content\">Dashboard Menu</div>");
```

This is using standard [web API Element.outerHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/outerHTML)

Answer (score 1):

Use [getByText](https://testing-library.com/docs/dom-testing-library/api-queries#bytext)

```
test("It should check if content matches", () => {
  const { getByText } = render(<Provider store={store}><TopBar /></Provider>)
  expect(getByText(/dashboard menu/i)).toBeTruthy();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [within](https://testing-library.com/docs/dom-testing-library/api-helpers#within-and-getqueriesforelement-apis) to get the text `Dashboard Menu`. Try this:

```js
test("It should check if content matches", () => {
    const { getByTestId } = render(
        <Provider store={store}>
            <TopBar/>
        </Provider>
    )
    const { getByText } = within(getByTestId('title-content'))
    expect(getByText('Dashboard Menu')).toBeInTheDocument()
});
```

Comment: The RTL team recommends using `screen` instead. `screen.getByTestId` vs destructuring { getByTestId } from render.

Answer (score 0):

if you need to have access to the type of HTML element itself, in addition to the contents, you may need to use `getByText` method with a callback func.

```
test("It should check if content matches", () => {
  render(<App />);

  const checkContent = screen.getByText((content, element) => {
      return element.tag.toLowerCase() === 'div' &&  content.includes('Dashboard Menu')
  });

    expect(checkContent).toBeInTheDocument();
});
```